# grub2 Windows doesn't boot anymore

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, windows

Hi. I had a Windows/Ubuntu 11.04 dual-boot setup and suddenly Windows stopped booting. I mean it doesn't even appear on the boot list. The files look fine and Ubuntu boots fine. I was trying to write a bootable SD card and I think I did `dd` on the wrong device. Here is my results made with the boot info [script](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/)

```
                      Boot Info Script 0.60    from 17 May 2011


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos5)/boot/grub on this drive.
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:  
    Mounting failed:   mount: tipo de sistema de ficheros '' desconocido

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7
    Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:  

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:  
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 11.04
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:  

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7
    Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /boot/bcd

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disco /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 60801 cilindros, 976773168 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             206,848   507,270,071   507,063,224   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         507,271,166   947,263,487   439,992,322   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         507,271,168   929,343,487   422,072,320  83 Linux
/dev/sda6         929,345,536   947,263,487    17,917,952  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4         947,263,488   976,771,071    29,507,584   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________

Disco /dev/sdc: 3980 MB, 3980394496 bytes
9 cabezas, 9 sectores/pista, 95977 cilindros, 7774208 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1    *          8,064     7,774,207     7,766,144   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda2        CCE8A9EEE8A9D6CC                       ntfs       OS
/dev/sda4        6C881B1A881AE1FE                       ntfs       HP_RECOVERY
/dev/sda5        450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409   ext4       
/dev/sda6        ec2f0f7b-769f-46db-8957-f8e8b7f7de35   swap       
/dev/sdc1        B805-7488                              vfat       KINGSTON

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdc1        /media/KINGSTON          vfat       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=999,gid=999,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)


=========================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #
    # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
    #
    # It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
    # from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
    #

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
    if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
      set have_grubenv=true
      load_env
    fi
    set default="5"
    if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
      set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
      save_env saved_entry
      set prev_saved_entry=
      save_env prev_saved_entry
      set boot_once=true
    fi

    function savedefault {
      if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
        saved_entry="${chosen}"
        save_env saved_entry
      fi
    }

    function recordfail {
      set recordfail=1
      if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; 
     then   save_env    recordfail; fi; fi
    }

    function load_video {
      insmod vbe
      insmod vga
      insmod video_bochs
      insmod video_cirrus
    }

    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409
    if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
     set gfxmode=auto
      load_video
     insmod gfxterm
     fi
     terminal_output gfxterm
     insmod part_msdos
     insmod ext2
     set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 
     450c3618-b8f1-4c80-     b767-6018e086e409
     set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
     set lang=fr_FR
     insmod gettext
     if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
       set timeout=-1
     else
      set timeout=20
    fi
    ### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
    set menu_color_normal=white/black
    set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
    if background_color 44,0,30; then
      clear
    fi
    ### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
    if [ ${recordfail} != 1 ]; then
      if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
       if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
         if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
           set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "$linux_gfx_mode" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 2.6.38-11-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-11-generic root=UUID=450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 2.6.38-11-generic (mode de dépannage)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.38-11-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-11-generic root=UUID=450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409 ro single 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 2.6.38-10-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic root=UUID=450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 2.6.38-10-generic (mode de dépannage)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.38-10-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic root=UUID=450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409 ro single 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 2.6.38-8-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic root=UUID=450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 2.6.38-8-generic (mode de dépannage)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.38-8-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic root=UUID=450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409 ro single 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 2.6.35-28-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic root=UUID=450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (mode de dépannage)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.35-28-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic root=UUID=450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409 ro single 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda4)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos4)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6C881B1A881AE1FE
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda5/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
# Commented out by Dropbox
# UUID=450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=ec2f0f7b-769f-46db-8957-f8e8b7f7de35 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=450c3618-b8f1-4c80-b767-6018e086e409 / ext4 errors=remount-ro,user_xattr 0 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

 414.013969421 = 444.544114688  boot/grub/core.img                             1
 280.472400665 = 301.154947072  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 242.948242188 = 260.863688704  boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic              2
 244.554271698 = 262.588149760  boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic              2
 374.640209198 = 402.266861568  boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic              2
 243.640205383 = 261.606678528  boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic               2
 242.479492188 = 260.360372224  boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic                 2
 243.815742493 = 261.795160064  boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic                 1
 374.550117493 = 402.170126336  boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-11-generic                 1
 248.460269928 = 266.782183424  boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic                  1
 374.640209198 = 402.266861568  initrd.img                                     2
 244.554271698 = 262.588149760  initrd.img.old                                 2
 374.550117493 = 402.170126336  vmlinuz                                        1
 243.815742493 = 261.795160064  vmlinuz.old                                    1

========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdb 

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

unlzma: Decoder error
```

Is there anything I can do instead of reinstalling everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried re-installing grub2?

Answer (score 0):

exactly I did that repair windows start up and then it breaks grub and you have to reinstall it again: here is a link if anyone needs more info https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Answer (score 0):

I am getting short of time...could not check whole your grub.cfg file. I do also have multibooting. You can check my grub.cfg file to get any clue to the solution:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd1,msdos8)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1ba4108c-e35d-45d5-9c64-3d4d085486bf
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f7550d0e-3364-45a3-81d0-8f423c94868f
  set locale_dir=($root)/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
if [ ${recordfail} != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "$linux_gfx_mode" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-13-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f7550d0e-3364-45a3-81d0-8f423c94868f
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.0.0-13-generic root=UUID=1ba4108c-e35d-45d5-9c64-3d4d085486bf ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.0.0-13-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-13-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f7550d0e-3364-45a3-81d0-8f423c94868f
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.0.0-13-generic ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.0.0-13-generic root=UUID=1ba4108c-e35d-45d5-9c64-3d4d085486bf ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.0.0-13-generic
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f7550d0e-3364-45a3-81d0-8f423c94868f
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic root=UUID=1ba4108c-e35d-45d5-9c64-3d4d085486bf ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f7550d0e-3364-45a3-81d0-8f423c94868f
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.0.0-12-generic ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic root=UUID=1ba4108c-e35d-45d5-9c64-3d4d085486bf ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f7550d0e-3364-45a3-81d0-8f423c94868f
    linux16 /memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f7550d0e-3364-45a3-81d0-8f423c94868f
    linux16 /memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Microsoft Windows XP Professional (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root E6C09302C092D85F
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Besides also check the boot.ini file in windows partition whether that exists okay. Best luck.

Comment: thanks BluE Sky, I have already solved the problem (that's why your answer has been accepted)